# accessing a chrome extension from outside the browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Is it possible to access a Chrome Extension from outside the browser?**

I would like to be able to run a command from my text editor ([MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)) that refreshes the page on which I am working.  From reading the [Chrome Extension documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html) it looks like I could try something really hack-y, like opening a page that uses [Chrome message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to refresh another page, but there does not seem to be a strait-forward way to do this.

I am running Mac OS X.  I've tried the shell command:

```
$ open <url>
```

But that opens a new tab every time in Chrome, so this doesn't help when I'm using the developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no straight forward solution.

Your hacky approach is the simplest way to go. Only instead of messaging I would put a tab creation listener into background page, and when a tab with some special URL is created (`http://example.com/?do=refresh`) - close it and refresh the next selected tab. You will see new tab flickering, but that's as good as it gets.

You can also look into using [WebSocket API](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/websockets/basics/), for which you would need to write a server side app (which you need to call from your editor somehow). Not sure how this all might turn out.

Comment: i appreciate the input -- seems like a web socket w/ a simple python server might be the way to go